# Create option popup with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow, popupmenu

I'm trying to write some code that creates a popup on a website landing page. What I need is a popup, with some text, and two buttons with two different options. One of them makes the popup disappear and continue normally in the site, the other one leaves the page and redirects somewhere else. Given that I don't really now that much about javascript, i'm kind of lost with two pieces of code that, individually, do half of the things i need.

I know each part of the code gives the result I need, but i don't know how to join them in a way they work.

this part of the code opens a popup that allows to choose between staying in the page or leaving

```
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">test this</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
</script>
```

this peace of code is kind of grotesque and does'nt make much sense, but it opens a nice popup, i want to get the above options inside this, and not the text it shows right now

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
var q = "do you know how much is 2+2?";
var a = 4;
var c = "<h2>yyyyyeeeeeeeyyyyyyy</h2>";
var ic = "<h2>w*nker</h2>";
var response = prompt(q,"0");
if (response != a) 
{ alert("buuuuh"); }
else { alert("oh yes!!! oh yes!!!"); }
var o = (response == a) ? c : ic;
document.write("<BR/>");
document.write(o);
</SCRIPT>
```

so, i need one popup, with two buttons, leave page, stay in page... and then i will deal with customizations and that whole shananigans

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `confirm()` event in JS, the logic behind what you want it's pretty much this :

```
var popup = confirm("Do you want to leave the page ?");

if (popup == true) {
  window.close(); //For an example, but you could change the URL of the website to another on, or do whatever you want here...
} else {
        return false; //or open another popup, etc, you choose what you need over the function...
  }
```

Then you'd just need to call it after the prompt you made or in a button or anything you'd like it to be

Comment: so, as i understood this, this code: 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var popup = confirm("Do you want to leave the page ?");

    if (popup == true) {
      window.close(); //For an example, but you could change the URL of the website to another on, or do whatever you want here...
     } else {
            return false; //or open another popup, etc, you choose what you need over the function...
      };
     </script> 
should do it? because i placed it on the page and nothing happens :/